# Sequelize mssql: order by primary key and limit

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I want to run a query with results sort using the primary key and also limit the number of return results. For example:

`return Things.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'status',
      'otherField'
    ],
    limit: 2,
    order: [['id', 'DESC']]
  })`

when the query is build, it generate the following SQL statement:

`... ORDER BY [Source].[id] DESC, [id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY`

Because `id` is the primary key and the sort parameter is also `id` I get the following error:

`'A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.'`

I am using sequelize 3.30.4 with tedious 2.0.0 connecting to a Microsoft SQL server 2017.

Thank you.

Comment: same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The order array should contain arrays/tuples. Try this:

```
return Things.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'status',
    'otherField'
  ],
  limit: 2,
  order: [ 
    ['id', 'DESC']
  ]
})
```

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake when typing my question. My code does use tuples. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

By the default, **Sequelize** create `createdAt` column in each table. So you can handle this issue by doing like this:

```
return Things.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'status',
    'otherField'
  ],
  limit: 2,
  order: [ 
    ['createdAt', 'DESC']
  ]
})
```

Do the sorting by using column `createdAt` as the param, the sorting result have same result as you do with `id` column