# Issue with duplicate sort id on primary key Sequelize & Feathersjs

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

OK , so I managed to get the default sort order going using this  (thank you ) :

[How Can I set the default Sort order in FeathersJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015012/how-can-i-set-the-default-sort-order-in-feathersjs/49039381?noredirect=1#comment85134473_49039381)

this is pulling data from mssql

I added in an include in the hook to get related entities.

```
app.service("invoices").hooks({
  before(context) {
    const AssociatedModel = context.app.services.parcels.Model;
    context.params.sequelize = {
       include: [{ model: AssociatedModel }]
    };

    let { query = {} } = context.params;
    console.log(query)
    if (!query.$sort) {
      query.$sort = {
        id: -1
      };
    }
    context.params.query = query;
  }
});
```

The end of the SQL statement generated

ORDER BY [Invoice].[id] DESC, [Invoice].[id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;

and I get the error;

> "A column has been specified more than once in the order by list.
>   Columns in the order by list must be unique."

before I put the related entities in , it worked fine - but this breaks.  Maybe it relates to something like this old bug..?  [Sequelize mssql: order by primary key and limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868651/sequelize-mssql-order-by-primary-key-and-limit)

Or maybe I am implementing this incorrectly.